# why pytorch linear model isn't using sigmoid function

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I'm expecting that the linear model in pytorch yields `sigmoid(WX+b)`. But I see it is only returning `Wx+b`. Why is this the case?

In Udacity "Intro to deep learning with pytorch" -> Lesson 2: Introduction to Neural Networks, They say that the output is sigmoid:

```
̂ =(11+22+)
```

From the below code I was expecting y cap to be 0.38391371665752183, but it is just the value of `WX+b`, which I confirmed the output. Why is this discrepancy?

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import numpy as np

torch.manual_seed(0)
model = nn.Linear(2,1)
w1 = model.weight.detach().numpy()
b1 = model.bias.detach().numpy()
print (f'model.weight = {w1}, model.bias={b1}')
x = torch.tensor([[0.2877, 0.2914]])
print(f'model predicted {model(x)}')
z = x.numpy()[0][0] * w1[0][0] + x.numpy()[0][1] * w1 [0][1] + b1[0]
print(f'manual multiplication yielded {z}')
ycap = 1/(1+ np.exp(-z))
print(f'y cap is {ycap}')
```

Output:

```
model.weight = [[-0.00529398  0.3793229 ]], model.bias=[-0.58198076]
model predicted tensor([[-0.4730]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)
manual multiplication yielded -0.4729691743850708
y cap is 0.38391371665752183
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`nn.Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html) layer is a linear fully connected layer. It corresponds to `wX+b`, **not** `sigmoid(WX+b)`.

As the name implies, it's a linear function. You can see it as a matrix multiplication (with or without a bias). Therefore it does not have an activation function (i.e. nonlinearities) attached.

If you want to append an activation function to it, you can do so by defining a sequential model:

```
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(2, 1)
    nn.Sigmoid()
)
```

---

*Edit* - if you want to make sure:

```
x = torch.tensor([[0.2877, 0.2914]])
model = nn.Linear(2,1)
m1 = nn.Sequential(model, nn.Sigmoid())

m1(x)[0].item(), torch.sigmoid(model(x))[0].item()
```

Comment: The output from this model that you gave is different from torch.sigmoid(z). The code that I tried is m1 = nn.Sequential( nn.Linear(2,1), nn.Sigmoid())
m1(x). Is this correct?

Comment: The weights on the two linear layers are randomly initialized. If you define `m1` as `nn.Sequential(model, nn.Sigmoid())` where `model` is your standalone linear layer then the results will be the same. (see my edit above)

Answer (score 1):

Not surprisingly, PyTorch implements `Linear` as a linear function.

Why the sigmoid is not included?

1. well, in that case it'd be weird to call the resultant module `Linear`, since the purpose of the sigmoid is to "break" the linearity: the sigmoid is a non-linear function;
2. having a separate `Linear` module makes it possible to combine `Linear` with many activation functions other than the sigmoid, like the ReLU.

If the course says that a sigmoid is included in a "linear layer", that's a mistake (and I'd suggest you to change course). Maybe you're mistaking a linear layer for a "fully-connected layer". In practice, a fully-connected layer is made of a linear layer followed by a (non-linear) activation layer.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, a linear function *can* have a bias.

Comment: @Ivan Thank you, you made me realize that it's more complicated than how I wrote it. It'd be more correct to say that in linear algebra and related fields, a linear map doesn't have a bias. I read that in English it's made a distinction between "linear function" and "linear map", but honestly I think it's a sort of "weird workaround" for what it's simply ambiguous terminology, given than "map" is a synonym of "function", at least in Italian.

Comment: That's interesting, in French "map" is more of a synonym to "bijection", as in a "*one-to-one* mapping". I believe it's how programmers usually call the function that transforms a list/array/etc into a structure of equal size... Anyway, it's basically "affine function" in *calculus* and "linear map" in *linear algebra*.

Comment: I'm afraid your summary is wrong, so I'll try to summarize this math caveat. The function `f(x) = wx + b` is called a "linear function" in calculus and an "affine function/map" in linear algebra. In linear algebra, a linear function/map is `f(x) = wx`. Because "linear function" has this double definition, some people use "linear map" when referring to the linear algebra definition and "linear function" when referring to the calculus definition.

Comment: Yes there is a double meaning, and I agree on the actual difference, in definition, between a linear function and a linear map, where there is no bias in the latter.